# How can I generate 50 samples per period for an uneven sin curve?

Tags: matlab, math, plot, graph

I have a figure of an uneven sin curve where the label x is "time" and amplitude is 1. I cannot figure out the function as it is irregular. I need to generate 40 samples per second on Matlab. So, I need the required function for it. Thank you!!

I know how to solve for normal sinusodial functions.

Here is the figure!!

[image]

Comment: We can see your private sharepoint page.  Just add the picture to your post, or put it on some image sharing service.

Comment: So, your curve restarts every 1 time unit?  But the wavelength is a large fraction of a time unit?

Comment: Yeah, so I have to finally plot a Gaussian  noise

Comment: If the restart occurs regularly, as indicated by your image, then simply reset the initial condition of your sine generator at the restart interval

Comment: Umm... I need the sin function which should be something like y = A·sin(B(x)) where A is amplitude and B is the period. for a regular sin curve it is 2*pi

Comment: Question:  Does your curve restart at regular intervals as suggested by your diagram?  Yes or no, please.

Comment: Better ask at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This looks like phase shift keying.  If the digital data is `x(t)`, then `y(t) = A * sin(w*t + pi*x(t))`

Answer (score 0):

The function that will generate that curve in the figure is given by

```
x = linspace(0,12*pi,1e5) ; % the x-axis 
z = real(-1i*exp( (-1).^floor(x/(4*pi)).*1i.*x)) % the function

plot(x,z)
```

[image]

you can take it from here....

(I assumed you know about complex numbers and e^ix=cos(x)+i*sin(x) )

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fn(t):
    return (1 - (int(t/(4*np.pi)) % 2) * 2) * np.sin(t)

x = np.linspace(0,12*np.pi,1000)
data = [fn(t) for t in x]
plt.plot(x,data)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another variation on this theme:

```
import numpy as np;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;

pi4  = np.pi * 4;                              # sign changes every 2 periods 
x    = np.linspace ( 0, 3, 1000 );             # 3 different 'sign' periods
sign = 1 - 2 * np.mod ( np.floor ( x ), 2 );   # this is how the sign changes

plt.plot ( x, np.sin ( x * sign * pi4 ) );
plt.show();
```

You can put it all in one function as well, if you want.

In Matlab it would be a 3-liner:

```
x    = linspace ( 0, 3, 1000 );
sign = 1 - 2 * mod ( floor ( x ), 2 );
plot ( x, sin ( x .* sign * pi * 4 ) );
```